# Facebook API: Get comment likes via FQL

Tags: facebook, language-agnostic, facebook-fql

I am looking for a way to retrieve the list of users that liked a comment via the facebook API.

I am particularly interested in doing it via FQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself.

It is possible to query the "like" table using the comment "xid" as a "post_id".

```
SELECT post_id, user_id FROM like WHERE post_id = <comment xid>
```